# Android Layout: Screen scrolls to top of form when making a change

Tags: android, scrollview, tablelayout

I currently am working on an android app that makes use of creating calendarcontract events..essentially a lightweight calendar app. The form I have created uses a table layout inside a scrollview. I noticed that when I select a value from a dropdown in the form the page scrolls back to to the top of the form. I don't want this to happen. I want that the user stays where they are on the page rather than the page scrolling back to the top of the form. I have searched through the forums and I can't find any reasoning for this. I am not sure if I need to add something to the layout tag or what not. Has anyone ever come across this before. Below is the xml I used to create the form. Please let me know if you need any clarification on what I am talking about.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#76766e">

    <TableLayout android:stretchColumns="*" android:background="#b8b9c8" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableRow android:background="#FFFFFA" android:layout_marginTop="2dp"><TextView android:text="@string/event"/></TableRow>
        <TableRow android:background="#FFFFFA" android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"><EditText android:id="@+id/eventTitle" android:hint="@string/enterEventTitle" android:layout_span="2"/></TableRow>
        <TableRow android:background="#FFFFFA" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"><TextView android:text="@string/from"/></TableRow>
        <TableRow android:background="#FFFFFA" android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"><Button android:id="@+id/fromDateBtn"/><Button android:id="@+id/fromTimeBtn"/></TableRow>
        <TableRow android:background="#FFFFFA" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"><TextView android:text="@string/to"/></TableRow>
        <TableRow android:background="#FFFFFA" android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"><Button android:id="@+id/toDateBtn"/><Button android:id="@+id/toTimeBtn"/></TableRow>
        <TableRow android:background="#FFFFFA" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"><TextView android:text="@string/timezone"/></TableRow>
        <TableRow android:background="#FFFFFA" android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"><Spinner android:id="@+id/timeZones" android:layout_span="2"/></TableRow>
        <TableRow android:background="#FFFFFA" android:layout_marginTop="1dp" android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"><TextView android:text="@string/allDay"/><CheckBox android:id="@+id/allDay"/></TableRow>
        <TableRow android:background="#FFFFFA" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"><TextView android:text="@string/calendar"/></TableRow>
        <TableRow android:background="#FFFFFA"><Spinner android:id="@+id/calendars" android:layout_span="2"/></TableRow>
        <TableRow android:background="#FFFFFA" android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"><TextView android:textColor="#d81417" android:id="@+id/chosenCalendar"/></TableRow>
        <TableRow android:background="#FFFFFA" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"><TextView android:text="@string/repeat"/></TableRow>
        <TableRow android:background="#FFFFFA"><Spinner android:layout_span="2" android:id="@+id/repeatChoices"/></TableRow>
        <TableRow android:background="#FFFFFA" android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"><TextView android:id="@+id/chosenRepeat" android:textColor="#d81417"/></TableRow>

        <TableLayout android:background="#FFFFFA" android:id="@+id/reminderTable" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TableRow android:id="@+id/reminderRow"><ImageButton android:id="@+id/addReminderBtn" android:src="@drawable/delete_icon"/></TableRow>  
            <!-- rows get added here for adding reminders -->
        </TableLayout>
        <TableRow android:background="#FFFFFA" android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" ><TextView android:id="@+id/chosenReminder" android:layout_span="2"/></TableRow>
        <TableRow android:background="#FFFFFA" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"><TextView android:text="@string/descriptionTxt"/></TableRow>
        <TableRow android:background="#FFFFFA" android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"><EditText android:layout_span="2" android:id="@+id/calendarDescription" android:hint="@string/enterDescription"  android:inputType="textMultiLine" android:lines="8" android:minLines="6" android:maxLines="10" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width ="0dip"/></TableRow> 
        <TableRow android:background="#FFFFFA" android:layout_marginTop="2dp"><Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/saveBtn" android:text="@android:string/ok"/><Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/cancelBtn" android:text="@android:string/cancel"/></TableRow>
    </TableLayout>


</ScrollView>
```